# Expo / React Native Error : spawnSync lsof ENOENT

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I am working currently on an expo app and I recently came up with this issue : when I run `npx expo start` and then I press a to open the app on an Android Emulator I get this error :

```
› Opening on Android...
› Opening http://127.0.0.1:19000/_expo/loading?platform=android on Pixel_4_API_33
Couldn't start project on Android: spawnSync lsof ENOENT
```

I tried different emulators but I still get the error everytime...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `lsof` command is in the system's PATH.

Also you can try the command `npx expo start --clear`

Answer (score 0):

The error came from the fact that I did not have an ANDROID_HOME variable inside my PATH. I just followed the instructions [here](https://themindtreasure.com/3-easy-steps-to-set-android_home-environment-variable-in-mac-permanently/) and problem solved !